# Gimp- how to switch/exchange photo

Tags: gimp, photo-editing

I'm new to gimp. 
I have created a graphic where I used patches to trace and cut shapes. I've attached the image. I want to be able to create duplicate files using different colour sparkle images. 
I created this one by using a sparkle image then with the path tool traced my shape, etc..inverted, cut . The hair is one layer, the lips another
Is there a way to insert a DIFFERENT colour without repeating the entire trace path, from path, invert, cut process
Thanks

[image]

Comment: OMGOSh you're brilliant! Love doing this stuff and learning as I go!!

Comment: If this demonstrates satisfaction with an answer then "accept" the answer...

Answer (score 1):

An easy to use tool to change colors of photos or other elaborate structured sources is the Gimp inbuilt hue/saturation tool (*Colors > Hue-Saturation...*).

We can cange the hue of a color we had selected with an overlap according to our needs:

[image]

By this different colors are only a slider movement away:

[image][image]
[image][image]

The effect only affects selected areas. For different layers we will have to note down the numerical values for the same effect on all layers.

Comment: Perfect!!  So basic, yet to a newbie- it's gold!!

Comment: @BrendaFunari: things hidden in dialogs are never basic - it is a rather nice function because it does shift colors rather than completely replace them. So the results look rather natural.

Answer (score 0):

### For a completely different fill

Just alpha-lock the layer and bucket-fill (pattern, color...). The alpha-lock will make the pixels keep their opacity (especially their partial opacity, for the ones of the edges, so you keep the smooth edges).

[image]

### To change the color or some other global aspect

- Create a layer group
- Put the layers you want to alter in the group
- Add a new layer as the first on top of the group
- bucket fill that layer and set to appropriate mode (screen, color, overlay...)

[image]

- Note that eyes/name/tagline don't change color because they aren't in the group
- You can have several color layers at the top of the group and toggle their visibility to keep different options in the same XCF file (and you can still edit the lips/hair layers).

Answer (score 0):

This is for GIMP 2.10 - which can now do layer masking on groups.

Basically, put all the images you want to use as a fill inside a layer group.

Create your shapes with the Pen tool, convert the paths to a selection.

Apply a layer mask to the Group, and use the "from selection" option when the layer mask dialog pops up.

Then you can simply hide or reveal the images in the group, or insert new images into the group.

[image]

It's also possible to use *Colors > Colorize* on each of these layers to change the colours of the images.

[image]

Another possibility is to add a solid filled colour layer above the images in the group, and set the colour mode to "Color (HSL)".  Then you can use the Hue-Saturation filter on that layer to control the colours.  This makes everything editable in a non destructive way. The original images are not altered at all, nor are they cut out, and the layer mask can also be edited.

[image]